# Vuex assign null conditionally in action

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have this action in my store:

```
updateTicketCustomer ({commit, state}, selectedCustomer) {
    axios.patch('/tickets/' + state.currentTicket.id, {
      customer_id: selectedCustomer.id
    })
    .then((response) => {
            commit('UPDATE_TICKET_CUSTOMER', selectedCustomer)
    });  
}
```

If I wanted to assign null to customer_id, what is the right way to do it? Given that in template I assign null to selectedCustomer, how do I build the conditional to assign null or selectedCustomer.id?

Something like

```
if (selectedCustomer !== null) {
    customer_id: selectedCustomer.id 
} else {
    customer_id: null
}
```

Comment: @mthrsj Why have you removed the `!== null` in OP's question ? Are you really sure it fits what OP had in mind ?

Comment: @Seblor it wans't there on the original question. I just formatted the code, but it's already fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
updateTicketCustomer ({commit, state}, selectedCustomer) {
    axios.patch('/tickets/' + state.currentTicket.id, {
      customer_id: selectedCustomer !== null ? selectedCustomer.id : null
    })
    .then((response) => {
            commit('UPDATE_TICKET_CUSTOMER', selectedCustomer)
    });  
}
```

The syntax is, basically:

```js
<condition> ? <returned if true> : <returned if false>
```